# Can't create new folders on SD card to backup many file

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I'm trying to backup an Directory but I stuck at I can't create new folders.

First, I give permissions to Manifest and already requested Runtime Permission:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Note: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` on my device return Internal Storage instead of SdCard. However, I used File Picker to pick file from SdCard and **READ** its data correctly.

But, this is my method to backup dir:

```java
private void backupSmaliDir(String smaliDir){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    String backupDirPath = smaliDir+"-BACKUP";
    StringBuffer listFile = getAllFiles(new File(smaliDir));
    String[] lines = listFile.toString().split("\n");

    result.append(String.format("BACKUP DIR: %s\nHAVE %s file to backup\n", backupDirPath, String.valueOf(lines.length)));
    try {
        for (String path : lines) {
            File f = new File(path.replaceFirst(smaliDir, backupDirPath));
            File newf = f.getParentFile();
            result.append(String.format("\n Old: %s\n New: %s\n", path, newf.getCanonicalPath()+"/"+ new File(path).getName()));

            boolean isCopied = false;
            result.append(String.format("[w] EXISTS: %s | MKDIRS: %s\n", newf.exists(), newf.mkdirs()));
            if  (newf.exists() || newf.mkdirs()) {
                // just copy path (FILE) to newf (FILE)
                File fi = new File(path);
                File fo = new File(newf.getCanonicalPath()+"/"+fi.getName());
                copyFileUsingStream(fi, fo);
                isCopied = true;
            }
            if (isCopied) result.append("\tCopied!\n");
            else result.append("\tCanceled!\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    saveBackupLog(result.toString());
}
```

I don't know why `newf.exists() || newf.mkdirs()` always return **False**, that means I have no new Directory on SdCard.

There is some result Log:

```
Smali Directory: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali

BACKUP DIR: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali-BACKUP
HAVE 141 file to backup

 Old: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali/android/support/v9/app/a.smali
 New: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali-BACKUP/android/support/v9/app/a.smali
[w] EXISTS: false | MKDIRS: false
    Canceled!

 Old: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali/android/support/v9/app/aa.smali
 New: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali-BACKUP/android/support/v9/app/aa.smali
[w] EXISTS: false | MKDIRS: false
    Canceled!

 Old: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali/android/support/v9/app/ab.smali
 New: /storage/AF7E-4CF0/toolbox/IPHONE_CONTROL_PSYCHO/smali-BACKUP/android/support/v9/app/ab.smali
[w] EXISTS: false | MKDIRS: false
    Canceled!
.....
```

Note2: If I backup a directory in ***Internal Storage*** like `/storage/emulated/0/tool`, this code work well!
So what wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try -> newf.setExecutable(true);

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 Thanks for advise, but it's not work including only create Folder **_backupDirPath_**.

Answer (score 0):

Add following into your manifest:

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...
```

as asking for `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is no more sufficient for Android 10+.